# Scala Test: how to assert lenghty exception message securly and clean without hardcoding?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, exception, coding-style

I have the following code, which is used to (sha) hash columns in a spark dataframe:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sha2,lit, col}

object hashing {

def process(hashFieldNames: List[String])(df: DataFrame) = {
   hashFieldNames.foldLeft(df) { case (df, hashField) =>
   df.withColumn(hashField, sha2(col(hashField), 256))
  }
 }
}
```

Now in a seperate file, I am testing my `hashing.process` using a `AnyWordSpec` Test as follows:

```
"The hashing .process " should {
// some cases here that complete succesfully 
"fail to hash a spark dataframe due to type mismatch " in {
  val goodColumns = Seq("language", "usersCount", "ID", "personalData")
  val badDataSample =
    Seq(
      ("Java", "20000", 2, "happy"),
      ("Python", "100000", 3, "happy"),
      ("Scala", "3000", 1, "jolly")
    )
  
  val badDf =
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(badDataSample).toDF(goodColumns: _*)

  val thrown = intercept[org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException] {
    val hashedResultDf =
      hashing.process(hashFieldNames)(badDf) 
      
  }
  assert (thrown.getMessage === // some lengthy error message that I do not want to copy paste in its entirety.
```

Usually, as I understand, one would want to hard code the whole error message to ensure that it is indeed as we expect. However, the message is very lengthy and I am wondering if there is no better approach.

Basically, I have two questions:

a.) Is it considered good practice to match only the beginning part of error message and then
follow up with a regex ? I am thinking something like this: `thrown.getMessage === "[cannot resolve sha2(ID, 256)  due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type, however, ID is of int type.;" + regexpattern \;(.*))`

b.) If a.) is considered a hacky approach, do you have any working suggestion on how to do it properly ?

Note: Small errors possible with code above, I adapted it for SO post. But you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be asserting exception messages (unless they are surfced to the user, or something downndstream relies on them).
If throwing an exception is a part of contract, then you should be throwing one of a specific type with a given error code, and tests should be asserting that. And if it isn't, then who cares what the message said?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering my own question. I now solved it like this:

```
  "fail to hash a spark dataframe due to type mismatch " in {
  val goodColumns = Seq("language", "usersCount", "ID", "personalData")
  val badDataSample =
    Seq(
      ("Java", "20000", 2, "happy"),
      ("Python", "100000", 3, "happy"),
      ("Scala", "3000", 1, "jolly")
    )
  
  val badDf =
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(badDataSample).toDF(goodColumns: _*)

  //val expectedErrorMessageSubstring = "sha2(`ID`, 256)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type".r
  val thrownExcepetion = intercept[org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException] {
      IngestionHashing.process(hashFieldNames)(badDf)  
      
  }
 thrownExcepetion.getMessage should include regex "type mismatch: argument 1 requires binary type"
}
```

Leaving this post open for potential suggestions / improvement. According to https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#intercepting-exceptions the solution is still not ideal.